# How to interrupt/break/stop forEach in ES6 Map?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a nice way (except using JS exceptions) to stop forEach loop in ES6 Map object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach )

From example provided on MDN - is there a way to stop enumeration on 'bar' (skip bar):

```
function logMapElements(value, key, map) {
    console.log(`m[${key}] = ${value}`);
}
new Map([['foo', 3], ['bar', {}], ['baz', undefined]]).forEach(logMapElements);
```

For the people who suggest to close this question: yes, it is similar to the questions about Array.prototype.forEach.
But at the same time is different: most of the suggested answers won't work with ES6 set and map. Only throwing the exception will work, but I ask for some other ways

Comment: It is similar, but at the same time is different. Most of suggested answers won't work with ES6 set and map. Only throwing the exception will work, but I ask for some other ways.

Answer (score 11):

There is no good reason to use `forEach` any more in ES6. You should use iterators and `for … of` loops from which you can ordinarily `break`:

```
const m = new Map([['foo', 3], ['bar', {}], ['baz', undefined]]);
for (let [key, value] of m) {
    console.log(`m[${key}] = ${value}`);
}
```

Comment: IE11 does not support iterators

Comment: @vmg Either switch to Edge or use a transpiler then :-)

Comment: @JDB `forEach` does *not* support chaining, it returns `undefined`. It is only suitable for side effects in the callback, and for side effects `for … of` is the better solution. For functional programming, you'll be looking for `map`, `filter` and the others that build on `reduce`.

Comment: @vmg It also doesn't support forEach, or does it?

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want for-of, the following approach can be applied:

```js
const length = myMap.size;
const iterator = myMap.entries();
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  const item = iterator.next().value;
  console.log(`myMap[${itemkey}] = ${value}`);
}
```

A benefit that I have personally encountered is that this approach produces less code during es5 transpilation (using Typescript transpiler with all its `__values` and `__read` definitions)...