# ternary operator inside an arrow function inside forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, foreach, arrow-functions

I have this little function that is supposed to remove object properties with even values.

```
function removeEvenValues(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => ((!isNaN(obj[k])) && (obj[k] % 2 === 0)) ? delete obj[k] : k);
}
```

In the else {} part of the ternary operator, how do I leave it empty like in an `if (true){ doSomething();}` kind of construct?  Or does it even make sense to use a fat arrow function in this case?

Comment: why use a ternary?

Comment: ternary (3 operands) makes no sense if you just want to use 2 operands.

Comment: @Bergi really? (he asked rhetorically) - I could swear this has come up before and I must have looked it up then too. (I almost never use it.)

Comment: @Pointy: [Yup](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-delete-operator). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you shouldn't use a concise arrow function or a ternary operator here. Well, you [*could* use `&&`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6970346/1048572) [instead of the ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15009278/1048572), but you really shouldn't.

You [shouldn't even use `forEach` in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31344612/1048572) - just use a proper loop:

```
function removeEvenValues(obj) {
  for (const k of Object.keys(obj))
    if (!isNaN(obj[k]) && obj[k] % 2 === 0)
      delete obj[k];
}
```

or (as you probably don't care about inherited properties)

```
function removeEvenValues(obj) {
  for (const k in obj)
    if (!isNaN(obj[k]) && obj[k] % 2 === 0)
      delete obj[k];
}
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out how `in` differs from `Object.keys` in terms of the properties handled, particularly as `delete` won't delete the inherited ones.

Comment: Why should you not use forEach? What is the reasoning behind that?

Comment: @epascarello `forEach` is only good for side effects, and for side effects `for … of` *statements* are the better solution. People shouldn't use `forEach` for looping, they just tend to try [using `break`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42728174/1048572), [using `yield`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34104231/1048572) or [using `await`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572) within it.

Comment: @epascarello: It's just an opinion, not a generally-accepted rule. Perfectly fine to use `forEach` in ES2015+ if you want to, provided you don't need to do something it doesn't support (such as stopping early -- in that case, use `some`). But as of ES2015+, there's no strong *reason* to use it unless it happens that you already have a function lying around that does what you want, and `for` plays better with some of the newer structures. You no longer need `forEach` for handy scoping of your loop-local vars, so you can avoid creating and calling functions unnecessarily by using a `for`.

Comment: @Bergi than they should be using `some` or `every` if they are looking for reason to break out. So basically it is your personal opinion on should not use forEach. ;)

Comment: @epascarello No, `some`/`every` are for getting a boolean result, not for performing side effects. One should use the right tool that shows the *intent* of the code best, and `forEach` does look functional despite being imperative. But yes, that's just my professional opinion, and while knowing when which hack might be appropriate I just tend to recommend to generally avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using a fat arrow, as it is a function expression, but because you are not returning a value, you shouldn't use a ternary operator. You can do:

```
function removeEvenValues(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {if(!isNaN(obj[k]) && (obj[k] % 2 === 0)) {delete obj[k]}});
}
```

Comment: Or if you feel a *really strong need* to avoid `if`, `&&` is basically the two-operand conditional operator: `k => !isNaN(obj[k]) && obj[k] % 2 === 0 && delete obj[k]` No, I am not advocating that. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This would also work fine, but not as readable; but it will probably end up looking close to this if you minify it :P

Comment: @ Joe - Hence my not advocating it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) and remove some superfluous parentheses.

```js
function removeEvenValues(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => !isNaN(obj[k]) && obj[k] % 2 === 0 && delete obj[k]);
}

var o = { foo: 41, bar: 42 };
removeEvenValues(o);

console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nina wrote, you can use logical operators instead of the ternary operator. You can also turn the condition around and use `||`.

Be aware though what `isNaN` returns. For instance `isNaN([2]) === false`! So instead you might want to test for the primitive number type with `typeof`.

Finally, recently the `Object.entries` method has found its way in some browsers, and in this case it can be nice to use instead of `Object.keys`:

```js
function removeEvenValues(o) {
    Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => typeof v != "number" || v % 2 || delete o[k]);
}

// Sample
var obj = {
    "a": 2,
    "b": "hello",
    "c": [4],
    "d": 5,
    "e": 6
};

removeEvenValues(obj);

console.log(obj);
```